# Laravel retorna atributos vazios no método edit

Tags: php, laravel, atributos, orm, collection

Tenho outra rota semelhante funcionando perfeito, não sei o que deixei passar.. agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

**Route**:

```
Route::get('/itensnfe/{itemnfe}/edit', 'ItensNfeController@edit')->name('itensnfe.edit');
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ItemNfe;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ItensNfeController extends Controller{
    public function edit(ItemNfe $itensNfe)
    {        
        dd($itensNfe);        
    }
}
```

**Model**:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ItemNfe extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'itens_nfe;'

  

  protected $primaryKey = 'id_itemnfe';

    protected $fillable = ['id_itemnfe','fk_nfe','cprod','cean','xprod','ncm','cfop','ucom','qcom','vuncom'
        'vprod','ceantrib','utrib','qtrib','vuntrib','vfrete','indtot',
        'nitemped',
        'vtottrib','orig','csosn',
        'cenq','cst','vbc','pipi','vipi',
        'cst_pis','vbc_pis','ppis','vpis',
        'cst_cofins','vbc_cofins','pcofins','vcofins'
    ];

    public function nfe()

    {

        return $this->hasOne('App\Nfe');

    }

}
```

**Resultado do "dd($itensNfe);"**:

> App\ItemNfe {#1272 ▼
>    #table: "itens_nfe"
>    #primaryKey:
> "id_itemnfe"
>    #fillable: array:34 [▶]
>    #connection: null
> #keyType: "int"
>    +incrementing: true
>    #with: []
>    #withCount: []
>    #perPage: 15
>    +exists: false
>    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
>    #attributes: []
>    #original: []
>    #changes: []
>    #casts: []
>    #classCastCache: []
> #dates: []
>    #dateFormat: null
>    #appends: []
>    #dispatchesEvents: []
>    #observables: []
>    #relations: []
>    #touches: []
>    +timestamps: true
>    #hidden: []
>    #visible: []
>    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
>  }

Comment: O que você está enviando no parâmetro `itemnfe`?

Comment: Estou apredendo laravel agora, pelo que entendi esse método está lendo a url: https://localhost/erpoverweb/public/itensnfe/7/edit

Comment: Nesse caso, você só está enviando um inteiro, então basta você colocar no parâmetro da função ` public function edit(ItemNfe $itensNfe)` assim: ` public function edit($itensNfe)`,

Comment: Esse `7` é o codigo do ItemNFE?

Comment: isso.. vou adicionar a pergunta, é o "id_itemnfe"

Answer (score 1):

Pra você retornar o item do seu model no seu controler, você precisa fazer o instanciamento do objeto buscando pelo código

Por Exemplo:

```
use App\ItemNfe;
class ItensNfeController extends Controller{
    public function edit( $itemnfe)
    {      
        $itemNfe = ItemNfe::find( $itemnfe);
        dd( $itemNfe );        
    }
}
```

Fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Espero que ajude

Comment: Funciona sim amigo, porém eu gostaria de saber o por que da outra forma não funcionar, porque eu tenho uma tabela de "empresa", que foi montada da mesma forma e retorna os atributos normalmente. A única diferença no outro caso, é que no banco de dados possui apenas um registro e nesse caso exitem vários. Já testei deixando apenas um registro como no outro caso mas não mudou nada.

Comment: Na rota você está passando apenas o id do item, e não o objeto todo, o que eu acho que não seria possível via get, apenas via post, mesmo assim, teria que receber os dados

Comment: Neste link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers você pode ver que mesmo se usar o "Route::resource" o que é gerado no sistema é uma rota GET. Eu acredito que o Eloquent já faz a consulta automaticamente pelo ID informado, pois tenho outra tabela até onde eu percebi, é idêntica e preencheu os atributos. Posso adicionar o código referente a tabela empresa na pergunta para comparar? O senhor pode editar ou apagar depois.

Comment: Note que você está usando um Route:;get

Comment: No resource, ele te ajuda na geração de rota e não na busca automática de itens

Comment: Sim, mas o Framework faz essa busca automática, pois tenho uma rota, controller, model para tabela clientes, que até onde analisei, idêntica, e fazendo o "vardump" da variável pega no get, retorna todos atributos. Eu imagino que deva estar ocorrendo algum erro por conta da convenção do Laravel referente a palavras no plural ou singular, mas não identifiquei ainda. Já passei inclusive o comando "composer dump-autoload" e não resolveu.